# How to autoexpand everything on a view translation edit form?

Tags: 8, views, i18n-l10n

To fully translate a view into one language I have to expand dozens of collapsed panels, most of them with only one or two subelements.

[image: example screenshot]

I've reported it [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3186427). But is there a quick workaround, like a module or setting that automatically expands all these panels?

I tried using `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` but changing the `#open` value is ignored (note that it's a top-level Displays panel `#open` which is `true` by default):

```php
 /**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function custom_admin_form_config_translation_edit_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  foreach ($form['config_names'] as $key => $config_name) {
    if (substr( $key, 0, 1 ) !== '#') {
      $display = $config_name['display'];
      $display['#open'] = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's set to closed at
https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/8.9.x/core/modules/config_translation/src/FormElement/ListElement.php#L70

by

```php
            '#open' => empty($base_key),
```

so I'll just add a patch to composer to change it to

```php
            '#open' => true,
```